# A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: ) Appium error

Tags: appium

I am doing automation testing for Android device . **In Emulator it's working fine** . While connecting to device it's creating & installing a unlock.apk to android device . After that following error is coming[image]

i have set below for configuration 
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");

```
       capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Moto C Plus");
    //capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "ZZ22cdddP9");
    //  capabilities.setCapability("udid", "ZZ22cdddP9");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");
    //capabilities.setCapability("Device Id", "xxxxxxxx");
          capabilities.setCapability("app", "D:\\abc.apk");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.s.abc"); 
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.s.sn");
```

Comment: You are setting deviceName=device serial number which is wrong. udid=deviceSerialNumber is correct.

Comment: i had tried that way also same error

Comment: have you even run appium on real devices . can you please help me sharing your configuration code . While running the application io.appium.unlock & io.appium.setting is installing in mobile but session is not creating to run Test cases

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Shiv & Vinod ,

Finally resolved those issue .. i was putting wrong activity name . so it was getting shut . By setting below line in capability it's working fine  capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.example.main.LaunchActivity");

```js
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "ZZ22cdddP9");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("app", "D:\\abc.apk");
   capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.s.abc"); 
   capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.example.main.LaunchActivity");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code before you initialize your appium driver.

```
String cmd = "adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release";

String osVersion=executeCommand(cmd);

if(osVersion.contains("7"))
{
    //uninstall io.appium.settings
    cmd="adb uninstall  io.appium.settings";
    executeCommand(cmd);

    //uninstall io.appium.unlock
    cmd="adb uninstall  io.appium.unlock";
    executeCommand(cmd);

}

public String executeCommand(String cmd)
{
    String commandresponse="";
    try
    {
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc=run.exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    String response=null;
    while ((response = stdInput.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        if(response.length()>0)
        {
            commandresponse=commandresponse+response;
        }
    }

    while ((response = stdError.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        commandresponse=commandresponse+response;

    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//System.out.println(commandresponse);
return commandresponse;
```

}

Comment: can you please tell me how to add application path in appium 1.6.5

Comment: how to upload apk in appium 1.6.5

Comment: hi .. i resolved those issues .. A new problem arrised .. session has been terminated .. how to resolve this

Comment: Hi Vinod . I had resolved those issues .. One problem is there .. i need help for scrolling in android scrren .. driver.swipe is not working .. i had tried JS executer.. can you help me with this

Answer (score 0):

```
Set following capabilities only and try to start appium :
Note : deviceName should be name which we will get using "adb devices" command.

   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "ZZ22cdddP9");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("app", "D:\\abc.apk");
   capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.s.abc"); 
   capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.s.sn");
```

Comment: my problem is when i comment out  capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.splashAnimation.SplashAnimation"); this my app is lunching in my mobile .. but when i uncomment above line  app is not lunching .. Finally in my test cases element not locating error is coming

Comment: what should i do .. plese suggest me ..  setting device name with actual as "samsung" or adb devices i.e "zz22cdddP9" is ok .. both are same but in my case .. My application is  not lunching .. when i do //capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.splashAnimation.SplashAnimation"); . app is lunching but it could not find the element required to perform the test cases ..

Comment: i had done same way as you are suggesting .. Please help me out with above problem ..  Also added session overirde as true &   capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
     capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, false);

Comment: Hi Shiv, I had resolved those issues .. One problem is there .. i need help for scrolling in android scrren .. driver.swipe is not working .. i had tried JS executer.. can you help me with this

Comment: You can define x and y points from where you want to scroll and duration driver.swipe(end_x, star_y, star_x , star_y, 1000);

Comment: For launching with activity you have to use  Main activity - it can be splash , Launch , Main activity.